# List all-childpages on parent-page AND list child-pages on childpage itself but not the current one?

Tags: functions, pages, wp-list-pages, child-pages

I have the following function that lists all Child-Pages of a page.

```
function show_subpages() {

    global $post;
    $subpages = wp_list_pages( array(
        'echo'          =>0,
        'title_li'      =>'',
        'depth'         =>2,
        'link_before'   => '&mdash; ',
        'child_of'      => ( $post->post_parent == 0 ? $post->ID : $post->post_parent)
    ));
    if ( !empty($subpages) ) {
        echo '<ul id="subpages" class="wrapper">';
        echo $subpages;
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

So when I'm on the `parent-page` I see a list with all the child-pages.
If I'm on a `child-page` I see the same list with all the child-pages corresponding with the parent-page.

```
— My Parent Page
   — My Child Page Nr. 1
   — My Child Page Nr. 2
   — My Child Page Nr. 3
```

This is almost what I want! The only little thing I need to add is to remove the "current" page I'm on from the list of child-pages.

So imagine I'm on `My Child Page Nr. 2` I only want to list `My Child Page Nr. 1` and `My Child Page Nr. 3` but not "Nr. 2" since I'm currently on this one.

Any ideas how to add this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function show_subpages() {

    global $post;
    $subpages = wp_list_pages( array(
        'echo'          =>0,
        'title_li'      =>'',
        'depth'         =>2,
        'link_before'   => '&mdash; ',
        'child_of'      => ( $post->post_parent == 0 ? $post->ID : $post->post_parent),
        'exclude'       => ( $post->post_parent == 0 ? '' : $post->ID)
    ));
    if ( !empty($subpages) ) {
        echo '<ul id="subpages" class="wrapper">';
        echo $subpages;
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

`wp_list_pages` supports an `exclude` parameter. In the above, I've simply added `'exclude' => ( $post->post_parent == 0 ? '' : $post->ID)` to the parameter array.
It works analogous to the way you are already feeding values to `child_of`:
If the post does not have a parent, we feed `exclude` an empty string. If it has one, we feed it the current post ID.